# Get onActivityResult when returning from startActivityForResult in Adapter

Tags: java, android

I am trying to return some data when a user clicks back from the Activity.

I am calling startActivityForResult from the adapter, but when I actually press back from the Activity, onActivityResult never seems to be called

*Code is trimmed down for example*

**Fragment1**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_view, container, false);

    return mainView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    mAdapter = new Adapter(this.getActivity(), new ArrayList<Item>());
    mGridView = (StaggeredGridView) getView().findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    mGridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.w(TAG, "in activity result");
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    }
```

**Adapter**

```
public Adapter(Context context, List<Item> objects) {
    super(context, -1, objects);
    this.context = context;
    addAll(objects);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_view_item, parent, false);
    }

View recommendationLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.recommendation_layout);
    recommendationLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Activity.class);
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putBoolean("denyEditPermission", true);
            intent.putExtras(extras);

            ((Activity) context).((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, 1);(intent, 1);
        }
    });
    return view;
```

**Activity**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detailed_view);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    denyEditPermission = extras.getBoolean("denyEditPermission");
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("denyEditPermission", denyEditPermission);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: please try remove finish() and do super.onBackPressed(); instead

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Just tried now but still did not work.

Comment: super.onbackPressed you still have to do it instead of finish...now can you try to remove requestCode == 1 &&  in your onActivity result?

Comment: Yeah, i tried before/after and instead of. In the onActivityResult I'm outputting to the log before the requestCode is checked.

Comment: I do have another Activity which is called but is called from Fragment1 and returns OK. I had the feeling it was something to do with calling startActivityForResult in the adapter?

Comment: wait wait wait..sry i missed that part...you have to start the activity for result from the fragment

Comment: How do I access the R.id.recommendation_layout (sorry for confusing name its a RelativeLayout inside of grid_view_item) from the fragment as this is part of R.layout.grid_view_item.

Comment: one option is to use broadcast receivers..what do you think?

Comment: @JohanV@lennard I don't think there is a need to use `BroadcastReceiver` here :)

Comment: y not..broadcast receivers are easy to implement like interfaces and fun to use too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use `activity` context to start the activity, you will get `onActivityResult` callback in activity, not in fragment. To get callback in fragment, you need to use fragment context/start activity in fagment itself. I would suggest interface approach to fix the issue here.Create an interface and implement it in your fragment and when the `recommendationLayout` is clicked, call the interface method from adapter so that you can handle the click event in fragment itself.

Something like,

**Create an interface file -**

```
public interface RecommendationClickListener {

    public void onRecommendationClicked();
}
```

**Fragment:**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements RecommendationClickListener{
...
...
...

@Override
    public void onRecommendationClicked() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NextActivity.class);
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putBoolean("denyEditPermission", true);
        intent.putExtras(extras);

        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

    }

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    mAdapter = new Adapter(this.getActivity(), new ArrayList<Item>());
    mAdapter.setRecommendationClickListener(this);
    mGridView = (StaggeredGridView) getView().findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    mGridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

**Adapter:**

```
private RecommendationClickListener mRecommendationClickListener;


    public void setRecommendationClickListener(RecommendationClickListener recommendationClickListener) {
        this.mRecommendationClickListener = recommendationClickListener;
    }

View recommendationLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.recommendation_layout);
    recommendationLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mRecommendationClickListener != null) {
                mRecommendationClickListener.onRecommendationClicked();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried something similar to this but did it wrong. Thanks for showing me the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

The Broadcast solution is as follows:

**In Fragment**

Declare on top of the class

```
public final static String START_ACT = "com.yourcompanyname.appname.START_ACT";

private Radio radio;
```

On the createView initiate and register the receiver

```
    //Initiate our receiver
    radio = new Radio();

    //Activate our recevier
    getActivity().getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(radio, new IntentFilter(START_ACT));
```

Also in the fragment, create the receiver class and the mothod which calls the Activity

```
/**
 * Receiver Class
 * This setup checks for the incoming intent action to be able to
 * attach more messages to one receiver.
 */
private class Radio extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(START_ACT)){
            getDataFromActivity();
        }

    }
}

public void getDataFromActivity(){

    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity.class);
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putBoolean("denyEditPermission", true);
    intent.putExtras(extras);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);


}
```

After from anywhere in the application send message to our radio

```
context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Fragment1.START_ACT));
```